# Is there any way to use DML operation in SNOWflake using pyspark , am able to run select statement but facing issue in merge or create statement

Tags: python, pyspark, merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dml

Is there any way to use  DML operation in SNOWflake using pyspark , am able to run select statement  but facing issue in merge or create statement

Comment: Adding error logs and code which you had tried will help others to better understand the issue to provide relevant suggestions/solutions. Also, did you try referring the official docs of snowflake to resolve your query ? A Google search got me this doc which may help you resolve the issue https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#executing-ddl-dml-sql-statements

Comment: Agree for request for more information.  What kind of error are you running into and what have you tried so far?

Comment: pyspark serves an altogether different purpose for Spark Integration with Snowflake. It is for loading data into data frames and then pushing to Snowflake and vice versa. You can use the python connector for the 'CREATE' statement to create a table in Snowflake DB.

Comment: Did you get to solve this question? I am facing the same problem. I cant find any documentation about how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

With Spark Connector you can run the DML queries in scala. 
Use the runQuery() method of the Utils object to execute DDL/DML SQL statements, in addition to queries, for example:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#executing-ddl-dml-sql-statements
If you are using Python, you need to use the Python connector and not a Spark connector.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this helps.

```
import snowflake.connector
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='u-name',
    account='account',
    warehouse='wh-hane',
    database='db-name',
    schema='schema-name'
    )

cs = ctx.cursor()
try:
    cs.execute("USE WAREHOUSE xxx")
    cs.execute("USE DATABASE xxx")
    cs.execute("USE SCHEMA xxx")
    cs.execute("my-query")

finally:
    cs.close()


ctx.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes i was able to do it with python native connector but not with pyspark ..